# smooth scroll to name and ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this code to scroll smoothly to a div id, but not to a name:

```
$('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 70
    }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = "#";
        return false;
    });
});
```

and this one does the opposite:

```
$('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top - 70
    }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = "#";
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can I mix both codes to scroll to ID's and names in one code?

Comment: Add ID to your [name] elements. Because IDs are anchors in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the selectors. This way jQuery will use the first that it finds:

```
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href') + ',[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top - 70
```

Comment: Great, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone need it:

```
$(function() {
    $('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href') + ',[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top - 70
        }, 800, function(){
            window.location.hash = ="#";
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to do this with vanilla javascript?

The best solution I have found for doing this in vanilla javascript is to import the package https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll

Comment: There is a beautiful npm package here: https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question 100% but I think you could just search for the element by name using querySelector and then apply the scroll to your element that way.

I was looking for an easy scroll solution earlier and came across [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Worked like a charm and required a lot less code than any of the other solutions I found.

```js
var foo = document.querySelector('[name="foo"]');
var bar = document.querySelector('#bar');

foo.addEventListener('click', 
  function(){
  bar.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
 });
```

```css
.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center
}

button {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size 18px;
 }

.second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <button name="foo">Click Here</button>
</div>
<div class="second" id="bar">
  <h1>It's Working!</h1>
</div>
```